# Is it necessary to think of vectors as being columns or rows?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation, vectors

I am reading a text that defines a transformation $J=yHu$, where $J$ is a scalar, $y$ is a vector of length $m$, $u$ is a vector of length $n$, and $H$ is an $m$ by $n$ matrix. The text claims that $yH$=$H^Ty$. This does not make sense to me. In the original definition, it looks like $y$ should be a row vector. When I follow the row/column paradigm, I find that $yH=[H^Ty^T]^T$, and that $H^Ty$ is a matrix not a vector. Am I thinking about this correctly? Are we allowed to formulate $y$ as both a column and row vector, depending on which is convenient??

Comment: I think there is a typo. If $H$ is $m \times n$ then in order for $yH$ to make sense and $y$ is a vector, $y$ is $1 \times m$. $H^T$ is $n \times m$ which cannot be multiplied by a $1 \times m$ vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right: they are a little sloppy about column vectors and row vectors.

It's common to represent vectors as $n$-by-$1$ matrices, i.e. column vectors. A row vector, i.e. a $1$-by-$n$ matrix would be the transpose of one of these (and vice-versa)

$$\left(\begin{array}{c}1 \\ 2 \\ 3\end{array}\right)^{\! \top} = \left( \begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 2 & 3 \end{array}\right)$$

If $y$ is a vector of length $m$ (an $m$-by-$1$ matrix), $u$ is a vector of length $n$ (an $n$-by-$1$ matrix), and $H$ is an $m$-by-$n$ matrix then $yHu$ does not make sense. In terms of matrix dimensions:
$$(m \times 1)(m \times n)(n \times 1) = (m \times 1)(m \times 1)$$
You cannot multiply an $m$-by-$1$ matrix with an $m$-by-$1$.

What I think they mean is $y^{\top}Hu$, where $y^{\top}$ is the transpose. If $y$ is $m$-by-$1$ then $y^{\top}$ is $1$-by-$m$ and so we can make sense of $y^{\top}Hu$. Dimensionally:
$$(1 \times m)(m \times n)(n \times 1) = (1 \times m)(m \times 1) = (1\times 1)$$
A $1$-by-$1$ matrix is a scalar.

They seem to use $y$ for both a row vector and a column vector when they should use $y$ for a column vector and $y^{\top}$ for a row vector.

The transpose identity is $(Hx)^{\top} = x^{\top}H^{\top}$.

This idea is used everywhere. For a real vector space the scalar/dot product is $\langle x,y\rangle = x^{\top}y$. Making a transformation of the space sends $x$ to $Mx$ and $y$ to $My$. Hence
$$\langle Mx,My\rangle = (Mx)^{\top}(My)=x^{\top}M^{\top}My$$
So $\langle Mx,My\rangle = \langle x,y\rangle \iff M^{\top}M = I_n$ where $I_n$ is the $n$-by-$n$ identity matrix.

Answer (score 1):

The abuse of notation assimilating $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ to the **column vector** of its coordinates is a handy convention (the other convention, assimilation all the time with row vectors would have been as satisfying) once you deal with dual space $\mathbb{R}^{n*}$, elements of which are assimilated, this time to **row vectors**.

For example notation $\langle e_2^* , e_3 \rangle=0$ is naturally rendered by the row column product (itself completely analogous to a dot-product):

$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc}0&1&0\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}0\\0\\1\end{array}\right)=0$$

Thus, reversing a column vector into a row vector corresponds to the (non-canonical) identification of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{n*}.$ Doing this once again, from a row vector to a column vector is the identification of the bidual with the original space.

Comment: Thanks. So, is it correct to always think of vectors as either columns or rows? The text didn't mention the dimension of $y$, just that it is a vector of $m$ length. I wondered if there was a more abstract idea than row/column vectors being used. Based on the answers, there does not appear to be such a thing as a vector that is both/neither a column and row.

Comment: Yes, this convention to always assimilate an "abstract" vector to the "concrete" column vector of its coefficients is a kind of "blind stick" that allows you in particular to work in both the primal and dual space without much effort (for example the dual of a linear transform is assimilated to its transpose, or conjugate transpose on a vector space on $\mathbb{C}$). I will hopefully lengthen my answer to give an example of the fruitfulness of this approach.

Comment: That would be appreciated and perhaps answer my question better than the currently accepted answer. I don't know anything about dual theory.

Comment: The example I can write down (in a few hours) deals with conic curves. Its interest is that it is connected to the very roots of the historical uprising of duality, as sketched in my answer [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1999743).